# Encountered an error: Version error for package fivetran/fivetran_utils

Tags: dbt, fivetran

I hope someone can help.

When I try and install `fivetran/tiktok_ads` package via packages.yml I get an error, can anyone help or confirm if it is an ongoing bug?

```
 package: fivetran/tiktok_ads
 version: 0.1.1
```

I get this error message:

```
Encountered an error:
Version error for package fivetran/fivetran_utils: Could not find a satisfactory version from options: ['=0.2.9', '>=0.2.0', '<0.3.0', '>=0.2.0', '<0.3.0', '>=0.2.0', '<0.3.0', '>=0.3.0', '<0.4.0']
```

this is my full packages file

```
packages:
  - package: dbt-labs/dbt_utils
    version: 0.7.3

  - package: fivetran/fivetran_utils
    version: 0.2.9

  - package: fivetran/tiktok_ads
    version: 0.1.1

  - package: fivetran/stripe_source
    version: 0.4.3

  - package: fivetran/pinterest_source
    version: 0.4.0

  - package: fivetran/microsoft_ads_source
    version: 0.3.1
```

this is my dbt version info

```
installed version: 0.21.1
   latest version: 1.0.0

Your version of dbt is out of date! You can find instructions for upgrading here:
https://docs.getdbt.com/docs/installation

Plugins:
  - bigquery: 0.21.1
  - snowflake: 0.21.1
  - redshift: 0.21.1
  - postgres: 0.21.1
(condaEnv) chris@Chris bla-data %
```

Answer (score 0):

try to update your

- package: fivetran/fivetran_utils

from 0.29 to latest version

after that run the dbt command `dbt deps`

this command will update all your packages.

Hopefully doing this it will work